# AES PKCS7 padding

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I just start learning Bouncy Castle for AES encryption/decryption. I am using `AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING` with 256-bit key.

BC can encrypt and decrypt text successfully, however after decryption I notice that there are always a few padding of null (0x00), which therefore fails my hash comparison. For example, suppose original input string is `“1234567890”`, the decrypted byte array is always:

```
{0x49,0x50,0x51,0x52,0x53,0x54,0x55,0x56,0x57,0x48,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}
```

Why the padding is not `0x06,0x06,0x06,0x06,0x06,0x06`? And is there any way to deterministically tell the padding length (could be 0) after encryption so that I can get exactly the same string before encryption?

Comment: Your code would be helpful here. Most likely your buffer is a fixed size and you're not truncating it to the correct length, but it could be several things that are impossible to tell without code.

Answer (score 17):

When you specify **PKCS7**, **BC** will add the padding to the data before encrypting, and remove it again when decrypting. **PKCS7** with **AES** would always add at least 1 byte of padding, and will add enough data to make the input a multiple of the AES block size. When decrypting the padding is **verified** to be correct, and in the case of PKCS7 also serve as an indicator of how much of the last block of decrypted data is padding, and how much is real data.

If you try decrypting the encrypted and padded data without specifying PKCS7 in the decrypt step, the padding would still be in the decrypted data.

***Edit:***

To illustrate my point .. here is some Java code that encrypts "1234567890" with **AES/CBC/PKCS7**, and then decrypts it again both with and without the PKCS7 padding:

```java
public class BCTest {
    public static void doTest() throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        byte[] clearData = "1234567890".getBytes();
        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes(), "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec IVspec = new IvParameterSpec("0123456789ABCDEF".getBytes());

        // encrypt with PKCS7 padding
        Cipher encrypterWithPad = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING", "BC");
        encrypterWithPad.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, IVspec);
        byte[] encryptedData = encrypterWithPad.doFinal(clearData);
        System.out.println("Encryped data (" + encryptedData.length + " bytes): \t" + toHexString(encryptedData));

        // decrypt with PKCS7 pad
        Cipher decrypterWithPad = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING", "BC");
        decrypterWithPad.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, IVspec);
        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[encryptedData.length]; 
        int decryptLen1 = decrypterWithPad.doFinal(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.length, buffer1); 
        System.out.println("Decrypted with Pad (" + decryptLen1 + " bytes):  \t" + toHexString(buffer1));

        // decrypt without PKCS7 pad
        Cipher decrypterWithoutPad = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING", "BC");
        decrypterWithoutPad.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, IVspec);
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[encryptedData.length]; 
        int decryptLen2 = decrypterWithoutPad.doFinal(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.length, buffer2); 
        System.out.println("Decrypted without Pad (" + decryptLen2 + " bytes):\t" + toHexString(buffer2));
    }

    private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        return javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BCTest.doTest(); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```java
Encryped data (16 bytes):           602CAE14358D0AC5C96E2D46D17E58E3
Decrypted with Pad (10 bytes):      31323334353637383930000000000000
Decrypted without Pad (16 bytes):   31323334353637383930060606060606
```

When decrypting with the padding option, the output have been striped of the padding - and the cipher indicates 10 bytes of decrypted data - the rest of the buffer is 0 filled. Decrypting without the padding option, results in the padding now being part of the decrypted data.

***Edit2:***

Now seeing the original code, confirms my hunch. The methode `GetOutputSize` don't return the output size of the decrypted string, but only the maximum needed space in an output buffer. The methode have the following documentation in the BC code:

```java
/**
* return the size of the output buffer required for an update plus a
* doFinal with an input of len bytes.
*
* @param len the length of the input.
* @return the space required to accommodate a call to update and doFinal
* with len bytes of input.
*/
```

DoFinal returns the actual length of the decrypted data put in the buffer.

So in

```java
byte[] plainTextBuffer = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(data.Length - IV_LENGTH)];
int length = cipher.DoFinal(data, iv.Length, data.Length - iv.Length, plainTextBuffer, 0);
```

The `plainTextBuffer` would be slightly larger than the actual decrypted data - the actual length of data would be in `length`.

Comment: But - as you say - one byte of padding is always added, and since the bytes in PKCS#7 padding have the same value as the amount of padding you can never end with a byte with value `00`.

Comment: One byte of padding is always added - and then removed in the decrypt. You don't normally see the padding at all. My guess is that you print more from the buffer than is actually returned by the decrypt. What language are you using? What is the length of the decrypted data as reported by BC?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes - can you elaborate on the downvote? A decrypt ala this in java: `byte[] plainData = new byte[encryptedData.length];`
`int length = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData, 0); ` would give the output as listed in the question, if you disregard the length returned by the cipher.

Comment: Without the code in the comment I don't think it is clear that you expect the zero bytes to be the initial content of a newly created array. Actually, if you just update your answer to include above code and write your answer around it, I'd happily upvote.

Comment: This looks like a very probable answer now, thanks for the edit. Hopefully we can fully verify it when the question contains the code. Inverted downvote into upvote.

Answer (score 0):

i am using c# from bouncycastle. looks to me this might be a bug from bouncycastle, or at least bouncycastle c# implementation does not follow pkcs7 spec exactly.

my solution is to chop off the trailing bytes that are not included in the return length of DoFinal. still not very sure why there are padding of 0x00, which as said should not exist at all.

below is the code. i used AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING for both encryption and decryption.

encryption --->

```
        ICipherParameters keyParams = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", keyByte);
        ICipherParameters aesIVKeyParam = new ParametersWithIV(keyParams, StringToByteArray(IV_STRING));
        byte[] iv = ((ParametersWithIV) aesIVKeyParam).GetIV();

        IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING");
        cipher.Init(true, aesIVKeyParam);

        byte[] cipherText = new byte[iv.Length + cipher.GetOutputSize(data.Length)];
        Array.Copy(iv, 0, cipherText, 0, iv.Length);
        int length = cipher.DoFinal(data, 0, data.Length, cipherText, iv.Length);
```

decryption --->

```
        ICipherParameters keyParams = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", keyByte);
        byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
        Array.Copy(data, 0, iv, 0, IV_LENGTH);
        ICipherParameters aesIVKeyParam = new ParametersWithIV(keyParams, iv);

        IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING");
        cipher.Init(false, aesIVKeyParam);

        byte[] plainTextBuffer = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(data.Length - IV_LENGTH)];
        int length = cipher.DoFinal(data, iv.Length, data.Length - iv.Length, plainTextBuffer, 0);
```

Comment: You should update your original question with this  .. not add it as an answer ..