# How can i decrpty a message of A AES 128 CBC mesage

Tags: c, aes, padding, iot, cbc-mode

I have both my IOT device and Network using AES 128 CBC to transfer message.
Since AES 128 CBC need padding , that mean after i decrptyed there 's still some PADDED BYTE In the MESSGAGE.

I have test in my mcu with the function working ENCRPYTED AND DECRYPTED OK WITH PADDING .
(i can encrpytyed , padded the message, decrpyted, calculate the padded message on my MCU )
However I have no idea that my MCU know how many padded byte was cascaded in the message recevied from my Network.

THanks

Comment: So transfer the count of padded bytes with the message? Or transfer the length of the message? Why didn't you think of that?

Comment: There are different kind of paddings. The "simplest" padding is just adding x0's up to the AES blocklength (multiple of 16). On decryption the x0s get stripped off. This will work if the decrypted value is a character/string and the x0 is not a value itself. This will not work with any kind of ("random") data - here you need something like PKCS5 or PKCS7 padding that adds values which get removed (but this may lengthen your encrypted/ciphertext) +16 (AES blocklength) when the plaintext is exact (multiple) 16 bytes long.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks but i dont think so since it will increase overhead and cause the message contradict the message protoccol?

Comment: @Michael Fehr Thanks any nameing of the Pad x0 method since i got some google most of people suggest to use PKCS7 for enhanced security ...

May i know which are the  "COMMON" padding scheme ?
x0 vs PKCS5 vs PKCS7 ?
and my questions is 
since i am using PKCS7 padding , so i now RECEIVED a message from network with padded string inside it, so i CANNOT differentiate which are the REAL MESSAGE USELESS i used the method suggest by @ KamilCuk , thanks

Comment: Kindly see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28595657/8166854 that explains how PKCS7 padding is working. Maybe you edit your question and add a sample ciphertext in hex coding to see what the actual padding is.