# How to do encryption AES if length more than 16 character in 128 bit?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Following is the snippet of the code in Matlab which is filling zeros if the length is less than 16:

```matlab
function plaintext_zeros = zerofill(plaintext)

    if(length(plaintext) >= 1 && length(plaintext) < 16)
        for i = length(plaintext)+1:16
            plaintext(i) = 0;
        end
    elseif(length(plaintext) > 16)
        error('Input plaintext has to be between 1 and 16 characters.');
    elseif(isempty(plaintext))
        error('No input plaintext given');        
    end
    
    plaintext_zeros = plaintext;

end
```

Comment: AES is a block cipher. You encode 16 bytes per block.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/28592989/1216776

Comment: You need a [“mode of operation”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) to use a block cipher as part of a larger algorithm to encrypt data larger than one block.